# How to resolve Error: Internal server error (500), while importing data using One click demo import WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I am working on WordPress theme development and getting an error on one click demo import.
I have increased max execution time, but still getting this error.
It creates a log file in media but there is no error. 
My log file has the following content::

```
---Downloaded files---
The import files for: demotheme were successfully downloaded!
Initial max execution time = 300
Files info:
Site URL = http://demourl.com/live/demotheme
Data file = /opt/lampp/htdocs/live/demotheme/wp-content/plugins/demo_plugin/inc/importer/demo-files/content.xml
Widget file = /opt/lampp/htdocs/live/demotheme/wp-content/plugins/demo_plugin/inc/importer/demo-files/widgets.wie
Customizer file = not defined!
Redux files:
options -> /opt/lampp/htdocs/live/demotheme/wp-content/plugins/demo_plugin/inc/importer/demo-files/options.json 


------
New AJAX call!


------
New AJAX call!


------
New AJAX call!


------
New AJAX call!


------
New AJAX call!


------
New AJAX call!


------
New AJAX call!


------
New AJAX call!


------
New AJAX call!


------
New AJAX call!


------
New AJAX call!


------
New AJAX call!


------
New AJAX call!


------
New AJAX call!


------
New AJAX call!


------
New AJAX call!


---Importing widgets---
Primary : 

Search - No Title - Widget already exists
Post List - No Title - Imported
Recent Posts - No Title - Widget already exists
Recent Comments - No Title - Widget already exists
Archives - No Title - Widget already exists
Categories - No Title - Widget already exists
Meta - No Title - Widget already exists

Secondary : 

Tag Cloud - No Title - Imported

Footer 1 : 

Text - About Us - Imported

Footer 2 : 

Navigation Menu - Useful Links - Imported

Footer 3 : 

Custom HTML - Working Hours - Imported

Footer 4 : 

Custom HTML - Newsletter - Imported



---Importing Redux settings---
Redux settings import for: options finished successfully!
```

Below is my environment details::

1. Hosting server php version:: PHP Version 5.5.38
2. WordPress Version:5.2
3. One Click Demo Import Version: 2.5.1

Please suggest why this problem occurs?

Comment: Is your question about and your issue with the plugin called "one click demo import"? In that case, you should contact _them_ for support. SO is for when you're having programming issues with _your_ code. It's not a generic support for third party applications.

Comment: Follow this thread - https://github.com/proteusthemes/one-click-demo-import/blob/master/docs/import-problems.md

Comment: I have already followed this still I am getting same error

Answer (score 2):

500 error
That means PHP syntax error 
If you are using ubuntu server, to check your syntax error using this command.

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Comment: You can using putty software or our server's in build command prompt.

Comment: It gives me an output :: no files remaining